# The type or namespace name 'Pages' does not exist in the namespace 'OfficeDevPnP.Core' (are you missing an assembly reference?)CSOM

Tags: office-dev-pnp

I have installed the latest Version of OfficePnP.Core (2.6.1608.0) but I donot see the Namespace OfficeDevPnP.Core.Pages

[image]

Is there something else that Needs to be done ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you are using a deprecated version of OfficeDevPnP.Core

Use either one of these depending on your requirements:

SharePoint Online:
https://www.nuget.org/packages/SharePointPnPCoreOnline

SharePoint 2013:
https://www.nuget.org/packages/SharePointPnPCore2013

SharePoint 2016:
https://www.nuget.org/packages/SharePointPnPCore2016